# font awesome does not appear even after adding class name

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have added html code inside php, which works fine. Just issue is, font awsome symbol does not appear(display square box), which I used successfully before.

```
<link href="font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        echo '<div class="c1">
            <div class="item2">
                <div class="image2"> 
                    <img class="media-object" src='.$row1[image].'>
            </div>
                <div class="descriptionContainer2">
                    <span class="main-head">Italian  -  '.$row1[rate].' <span class="fa fa-star"> </span>  </span>
                    <span class="min-head"> '.$review.'</span>
                    <span class="subcont">
                    <span class="fa fa-phone"> '.$row1[phone].'</span> 
                            <span class="fa fa-home">'.$row1[address].'</span> 
                        </span>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>';
```

When I used same code in fiddle it displays correctly:

CHECK FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/9r74Y/4/

Comment: Have you checked the path to the font folder?

Comment: This can only be a path problem as the fiddle works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CDN:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

if they display with that in place then you know you have a path issue.

Cheers,
Ant.